# Perform a bartlett.test after group_by between two columns following an id

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr

I would like to perform multiple bartlett.test between values inside two columns following an id in another column.

Data

```
structure(list(moda = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("BS1", "HW1", "PG"), class = "factor"), 
t0 = c(1.5, 1.5, 2, 1, 1.5, 1.2, 1, 2.4, 1.3, 1.4, 1.7, 2, 
1.8, 2.3, 2.5, 2.5, 1.5, 1.5, 2, 2.1, 1.8, 1.3, 2, 1.5, 2, 
3.5, 1.5, 1.7), t14 = c(1.5, 1.5, 2, 1, 1.5, 1.2, 1, 2.4, 
1.3, 1.4, 5, 7, 2.5, 6.5, 5.4, 5, 6, 5.7, 7, 3.5, 4.7, 4.5, 
5.9, 5, 6, 7, 6, 5.5)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-28L))
```

Code

```
library(dplyr)
group <- function(data1, var1, var2){
  var1 <-  enquo(var1); var2 <-  enquo(data1$t0), var3 <-         enquo(data1$t14);
  data1 %>% 
    group_by(!!data1$moda) %>% 
    summarise(n = n(),
              bartlett.test(var2, var3))
}

group(df = data1, var1 = data1$moda, var2 = data1$t0, var3=data1$t14)
```

If it's possible to put the result in a dataframe and keep the id, it would be perfect.
EDIT: it's maybe better to use split before. And bartlett.test needs one column with value and one column with id so i don't know how to perform it in my case.

Comment: Usually in `bartlett.test`, first argument is the numeric variable and second is the grouping, factor variable. Docs mention: *Performs Bartlett's test of the null that the variances in each of the groups (samples) are the same.* So one call, `bartlett.test(data1$t14, data1$moda)`, is what you need. Splitting by *moda* or running `data1t0 ~ data1t14` results in error.

Comment: But i would conpare the variance between t0 and t14 not between only one variable, it s to prepare for a t test or a wilcox test. I can do a f test but it s less powerfull than bartlett